# Algorithms for Contextual Bandits (a.k.a. where is UCB?)

Tags: vowpalwabbit

Hello and let me start by saying I haven't really worked with **contextual** bandits before; I've worked a lot with multi-armed bandits, as well as with Monte-Carlo Tree Search. Anyway, I'm used to using UCB as my go-to for MABs, so I was very surprised when I couldn't find UCB in VowpalWabbit's documentation at all. As I understand, UCB isn't directly applicable to the contextual formulation of the problem, but there are adaptations such as LinearUCB that are.

My question is - what am I missing? Is UCB there, but under a different name? Has it been deliberately omitted as it is simply worse than another algorithm that has been implemented? If so, which is this(/these) algorithm and how is it better?

Answer (score 0):

VW has an RND explorer (see end of page [here](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Contextual-Bandit-algorithms)) which is equivalent to a randomized approximation to the LinearUCB bound, so it might be what you are looking for.